# How to customize the entries rows of Table Component in CDE PENTAHO?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have 12 rows in my resultset which I am rendering in the table component in CDE Pentaho. By default 10 entries is shown and next 2 rows goes to next page and for two rows i need to use pagination. My question is how to make by default show rows customize and show 20 rows by default. I want all my rows seen at once in first page. No need of pagination or next to see remaining 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Set 'Page length' in advanced properties of the table

Comment: I solved this problem using paginate as false. Anyway, thanks for your reply and support (@bhericher)

Comment: @paudel: You can post your solution as an answer to your own question and then accept it as a correct answer.